# Awk or Sed commands to remove duplicates from the CSV file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I do have the generated CSV file which contains the duplicate values .I would like to delete/remove that duplicate values using AWK or Sed commands.

Actual output

```
10.135.83.48,9042
10.135.83.46,9042
10.135.83.44,9042
10.5.197.25,10334
10.39.8.166,1500
10.135.83.48,9042
10.135.83.46,9042
10.135.83.44,9042
https://t-mobile.com,443
https://t-mobile.com,443
http://localhost:5059/abc/token,80
```

Expected output

```
  10.135.83.48,9042
    10.135.83.46,9042
    10.135.83.44,9042
    10.5.197.25,10334
    10.39.8.166,1500
https://t-mobile.com,443
http://localhost:5059/abc/token,80
```

From few of property files i got this output. Below is the script which i am trying

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(ls); 
do 
#echo  " --$file -- "; 
grep -P  '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|\.uri|\.endpoint)' $file|grep '^[^#]' |awk '{split($0,a,"#"); print a[1]}'|awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[1],a[2]}'|sed 's/^\|#/,/g'|awk '/http:\/\//  {print $2,80}
       /https:\/\// {print $2,443}
       /Points/     {print $2,"9042"}
       /host/       {h=$2}
       /port/       {print h,$2; h=""}'|awk -F'[, ]' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){print $i,$NF}}'|awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$1=$1} 1'|sed '/^[0-9]*$/d'|awk -F, '$1 != $2' 
done |awk '!a[$0]++' 
#echo "Done."
stty echo
cd ..
```

awk '!a[$0]++' --> This is the command i am trying to combine with above script. Individually this command is working.But when i am trying to combine with the above script it is not working as expected.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This should be inside the loop

Comment: I'd be curious to the see the format of the actual input files ... seems to me that there's an awful lot of grepping & awking going on ...

Comment: If order doesn't matter, just `sort -u` works, btw.

Comment: `for file in $(ls);` Don't do that. Use `for file in *;` See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for more.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *; 
do 
#echo  " --$file -- "; 
grep -P  '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|\.uri|\.endpoint)' $file|grep '^[^#]' |awk '{split($0,a,"#"); print a[1]}'|awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[1],a[2]}'|sed 's/^\|#/,/g'|awk '/http:\/\//  {print $2,80}
       /https:\/\// {print $2,443}
       /Points/     {print $2,"9042"}
       /host/       {h=$2}
       /port/       {print h,$2; h=""}'|awk -F'[, ]' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){print $i,$NF}}'|awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$1=$1} 1'|sed '/^[0-9]*$/d'|awk -F, '$1 != $2' | awk '!a[$0]++'  
done 
#echo "Done."
stty echo
cd ..
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to approach this (or one of the simplest) is to keep an array indexed by the records that have been seen. If the records isn't in the `seen` array, add it and print the record. If it is, just skip the record, e.g.

```
awk '$0 in seen{next}; {seen[$0]++}1' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in the file named `dupes`, you would have:

```
$ awk '$0 in seen{next}; {seen[$0]++}1' dupes
10.135.83.48,9042
10.135.83.46,9042
10.135.83.44,9042
10.5.197.25,10334
10.39.8.166,1500
https://t-mobile.com,443
http://localhost:5059/abc/token,80
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'H;x;s/((\n[^\n]+)(\n.*)*)\2$/\1/;x;$!d;x;s/.//' file1
```

Append the current line to the hold space (HS) and if it is a duplicate, remove it.

At the end of the file, swap to the HS, remove the first character (which is a newline artifact) and print the result.

N.B. This removes duplicates but retains original order.